# Выделить ли запятыми «дурачок»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

`Они решили уйти из соревнования. А я, дурачок, решил идти дальше.`

Кажется, обособить нужно, и если нужно, то как объяснить эти запятые? Или нужна таки другая пунктуация?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Они решили уйти из соревнования. А я, **дурачок**, решил идти дальше.*
>
> Кажется, обособить нужно, и если нужно, то **как объяснить эти запятые?**

См. [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120):

> **§ 63**. Нераспространенные приложения обособляются или не обособляются в зависимости от места расположения по отношению к
> определяемому слову, от наличия или отсутствия при определяемом слове
> других определений.
>
> <…>
>
> **4**. При отнесенности к личным местоимениям место приложения не играет роли, оно обособляется всегда: ***Инженер**, он великолепно
> знал свое дело; Он, **инженер**, великолепно знал свое дело.*

Answer (score 2):

**Еще один возможный вариант:**

*Они решили уйти из соревнования. А **я дурачОк**, // решил идти дАльше.*

Здесь **ирония**. По грамматике БСП, разделены запятой два простых предложения.  Дурачок — сказуемое.

**Сравнить:** *А Я, // **дурачОк**,// решил идти дАльше.*  Вставочная интонация, другие ударения.

Comment: Я, вообще, не использую синтагмы и фразы (пока что), но ваш ответ всë равно плюсану.

Comment: А я дурачОк, // решил идти дАльше. - произносится с паузой после я, тоже нужна запятая.

Comment: @Буратино
А вы произнесите без паузы, то есть так, как обозначено на схеме)

Comment: Спасибо, Максим за голос. Я уверена, что вам понравится метод интонационного анализа. Он совсем несложный, просто опыт нужен. Кстати, здесь нет синтагм (произносительных отрезков), только короткие фонетические фразы.

Comment: не произносится и у вас не получится, либо вообще не нужны запятые: а я-дурачок решил идти дальше.ну и написание, очевидно, тогда дефисное.

Comment: Как это не получится! Отвлекитесь от лексического наполнения и смотрите на грамматику. Вы не можете разделить предложения на две интонационные части? После первой части понижение голоса и грамматическая пауза.

Comment: Я знаю, что нет тут синтагм. Кстати, а почему обращение не с двух сторон выделили?

Comment: Случайно. К синтагмам это не имеет отношения)  У вас есть вопросы по интонационной схеме этого предложения?

Comment: @Sharon Пока что нет вопросов. Если что, в ответах на мои вопросы можете предлагать и варианты с фонетическим членением предложения, так больше понимать его начну. Кстати, а такие варианты с членением на фразы и синтагмы где можно использовать? Можно, например, при переписке с кем-либо? И где их в принципе используют?

Comment: Хорошо, я учту ваши замечания. Но по поводу правильности лучше поискать ответ в источниках. Использовать слеши не запрещено, но как лучше обозначить паузы? Двойной чертой я обозначаю грамматические паузы (рядом с запятыми), а одной чертой произносительные (нужны ли там пробелы?).  Есть еще одна тонкость: в сложном предложении происходит перераспределение ударений и пауз, и там лучше обозначать не все ударения и паузы, а только проблемные. То есть те, которые влияют на постановку знаков.

Answer (score 1):

Я, дурачок, считаю, что, дурак, нужно выделять запятыми в большинстве случаев.

Потому что дурак с семантикой "умственно отсталый" появилось намного позже. Дурак - это глухой, тот кто не слышит, не слышащий голос разума. Используется в качестве междометия или в качестве нарицательного, для обращения к тому кто тебя не слышит.

Ладно, почему обособляются фразы вроде "он, инженер, великолепно знал своё дело"?

Он великолепно знал своё дело, потому что он инженер.(причина)

Иначе может быть, если "он - инженер, великолепно знающий своё дело":

Он великолепно знает своё дело - инженер, одним словом!(вывод)

Теперь про дурачка. Есть фраза: я решил идти дальше. Как добавить дурачка?

Я - дурачок, - решил идти дальше. - Я решил идти дальше, но получилось, что дурачок. Но дурачок.

Я, дурачок, решил идти дальше. - Я поступил глупо, когда решил идти дальше.

А я-дурачок, решил идти дальше! - саркастическое самонарицание. - Дурачок! - решил идти дальше!

Comment: Здесь же ирония и ум.-ласкат. значение!  А вы рассуждаете о семантике слова "дурак".  ДУРАЧОК, -чка; м. 1. Уменьш.-ласк. к Дурак (1 зн.). Не притворяйся дурачком! Не разыгрывай из себя дурачка! Не бойся, д.! 2. =Дурак (2, 4 зн.). Дурачков в народе считают божьими людьми. Играть в подкидного дурачка. ●Иванушка-дурачок - простодушный герой русских народных сказок, которому природная смекалка и доброта помогают преодолевать все трудности и добиваться удачи даже в самых безнадёжных делах.

Comment: А еще здесь интонация, то есть фонетика русской речи.  Но учить фонетику никто не хочет, легче же правило выучить)) А то фразы, ударения..  Несложная наука, но ведь что интересно: эта наука будто ЗАКОЛДОВАННАЯ, все боятся к ней даже близко подойти.

Comment: Вы путаете слово и метаслово. И Кузнецов тоже путает.

Comment: Ага, я все путаю, вы меня не слушайте))  У нас официальный Кузнецов, ну Ефремова еще, а больше у нас и нет ничего. Словарь РАН еще, но он орфографический.

Comment: получается, я - дурачок)?

Comment: Ну что вы, сэр...  Я так не говорила...

Comment: Я объясню. Слово изначально задумывалось как название чего-то конкретного, либо явления, либо впечатления. А потом пришел Лакан и сказал, что семантический знак указывает на что угодно, кроме самого себя - означаемое без означаемого. И пошли клепать метаслова. Дурачок - это не дурачок, а умственно отсталый стало. А умственно отсталый - это сложный такой набор критериев, который вообще простому человеку не понять, а диагнозы ставят только доктора с дипломами - магистры и прочие маги. Доктор - от доктрина, от дек - согласие, то есть адепты согласия с неким учением.

Comment: И язык превращается в метаязык - набор условностей, не отражение реального мира, а отражение иллюзии мира. Поэтому современные словари, это просто отражение культурных тенденций постмодерна и метамодерна, а вовсе не инструменты для понимания, что такое язык.

Comment: Очень познавательно, сэр. Я всегда с удовольствием вас слушаю. Но это поэзия, высокая лингвистическая наука. А у на практика, и там свои законы.

Comment: Ваша практика не на законах основана, а на условностях, в том и проблема.

Comment: А вот здесь я сомневаюсь, сэр.  Вы очень хороши в теории,  но не цените практику. А кому нужны тогда ваши теории?

Comment: Голос от меня, вы очень забавно рассуждаете. Могли бы преуспеть в написании пародий.  "Интеллигент думает о смысле жизни".

Comment: Пародия на пародию - не пародия, по логике)

Comment: Эта фраза тоже хороша, сэр.